# Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am exploring Blockchain framework Hyperledger-fabric. I am able to install chaincode successfully but when I instantiate chaincode then i encountered with following error.
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown

Comment: Command that I run to instantiate chaincode:
 peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C TestChannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"

I verified all path also. I am new for hyperledger fabric.

Comment: are you trying to run a specific example or tutorial?

Comment: How do you create the crypto material?! With the cryptogen tool?! Are you sure that all the identificators from the configtx.yaml and the crypto-config.yaml are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems as you. just two advice. I doubt it is the cause of 
docker version in my case. But I have not verified it. I will try to see.
1. update the docker version.
2. check if the channel name is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today.

It's just because I type the lower case parameter "-c" (--ctor string) instead of "-C" (--channelID string) by mistake.

Comment: I did the same mistake. Thanks a lot for the hint!